# Working in simulator but not on Real device swift xcode alamofire

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, alamofire, xcode10

Working in simulator but not on device
i am getting data from api it's properly work on simulator but not working in real device

And gives a error No such module 'Alamofire'

here is my code ViewController.swift

import UIKit

import Alamofire

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

```
@IBOutlet var tableview: UITableView!

var TeamArray = [AnyObject]()
var BackArray = [AnyObject]()
 var countnew = 0
var timer = Timer()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Alamofire.request("https://www.WebLink.com/api/").responseJSON{
        response in

        if let DataResult = response.result.value{

             if let dictionary = DataResult as? [String: Any] {
                if let Result1 = dictionary["result"] as? [String: Any]{
                    if let nestedDictionary1 = Result1["inPlayEvents"] as? NSArray, let description = nestedDictionary1.value(forKey: "market") as? [[String: Any]],let description1 = description.first?["runners"] as? [[String: Any]],let BAck = description1.first?["back"] as? NSArray{

                        print("JSONResdsd : \(nestedDictionary1)")
                       // print("JSONEvent : \(description)")
                        self.TeamArray = description as [AnyObject]
                        self.BackArray = BAck as [AnyObject]

                         self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval:1.0, target: self, selector: "sayHello", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return TeamArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as?
    CustomTableViewCell

    let title = TeamArray[indexPath.row]["start"]
    let price = BackArray[indexPath.row]["price"]

    let x : Double = title as! Double
    let myString = String(x)
    let pricenew : Double = price as! Double
    let pricestr = String(pricenew)
    print("Price : \(pricestr)")
    print("INT : \(title)")
    //let BPrice = BackArray[indexPath.row]["price"]
 //  ToastView.shared.short(self.view, txt_msg: "HJJDFKH\(String(describing: BPrice)))")
    cell?.TitleLabel.text = String (myString)
    cell?.Back.text = String (pricestr)
   // cell?.Back.text(\())
    return cell!
}

@objc func sayHello()
{
    self.tableview.reloadData()
}
```

}

Comment: Unless you show code and a precise explanation of what works and what doesn't, no one will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you tell me how did you install Alamofire? As you can check on their GitHub readme page: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/tree/4.8.0 there are a few ways to add this library to project. I will recommend you using Cocoapods:

1) Install CocoaPods:

```
gem install cocoapods
```

2) Create `Podfile` inside your project folder:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

target '<Your Target Name>' do
   pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.7'
end
```

Replace `<Your Target Name>` with your target name.

3) Run:

```
pod install
```

4) Close your project and open a new file called `<Your Project Name>.xcworkspace` in Xcode

Comment: Make sure that you are using `.xcworkspace` not a `.xcodeproj` file to open project. Maybe you will need to remove `DerivedData`: `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`. Also, you should get more details error log during compiling, so maybe there will be more details.

Comment: Dear it's run in simulator(Virtual Device) not run in real(I PHONE) device